# Most voted up answers at Cross Validated?

Tags: support, answers, votes, search

What is the best way to view the most voted up (or highest scored) answers and questions at Cross Validated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use searches like

> [score:100 is:answer wiki:no](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=score%3a100%20is%3aanswer%20wiki%3ano)
>
> [score:100 is:question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=score%3a100%20is%3aquestion)

Replace `100` by whatever lower threshold you wish to use.  I like to add `wiki:no` to these searches to skip over the favorite jokes, *etc*.

For more information, visit [the advanced search help page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Answer (score 4):

@whuber has provided some good options.  Let me address this more directly:  If you are interested in *answers*, you can search for `is:answer`, then just sort by votes.